# Excel: Using Index function with Defined Names to reference array

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, vlookup

I've created an array with defined names, and I want to reference the value of a particular cell using the defined names.
Row 8 is defined as "BidLevel3", and Column H is defined as "ContractCPrice".
I want to enter the formula "=INDEX(BidLevel3,ContractCPrice)" to return the value 9 which is in Cell H8, but it's giving me a "#REF!" error.

Is there an easier way to do this?

[Defined Names for Rows and Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZwFW.png)

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```
=INDEX($A$1:$H$8,row(BidLevel3),column(ContractCPrice))
```

...adjusting "$A$1:$H$8" according to the position of your table.